# Win 10 Pro cannot see or ping Server and NAS in Network Environment

Tags: windows-10, networking, nas, file-sharing, network-discovery

I currently struggle to get a new lenovo laptop to properly connect to the local network.

When I check the network environment neither the Server nor the NAS we are running here shows up. I can also not ping either of them via IP nor name. Also, I cannot add them manually as network drives, regardless of what I tried.

I've kind of exhausted my options and researching online gives me 99.99% the same advice that I already tried unsuccessfully.

What I've done so far:

1. Set network to private
2. Activate network discovery
3. Deactivate TCP/IPv6 in the network adapter
4. Activate SMB 1.0 in Windows-Features
5. Set the following services on automatic:
   Function Discovery Provider Host;
   Function Discovery Resource Publication;
   SSDP Discovery;
   UDnP Device Host;
6. run "ipconfig /flushdns" in cmd after changing settings
7. add IPs and names to c/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
8. turn on/off all firewalls
9. sacrifice offerings to satan
10. reset network settings and try again

None of the other computers seem to have any issues. Everything is always fully updated.

I hope someone with more knowledge could help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my RaspberryPi NAS. I tried all the things you did and then discovered that my eero mesh system had a subnet mask 255.255.252.0 while the RaspberryPi had a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0, a much large range for the eero mesh. My laptop that could not see the NAS had an ip 192.168.7.253, while the RaspberryPi was 192.168.4.38. Note the 7 versus the 4. The Pi could not see the laptop. Other computers in our house that had a 4 in the third subnet octet could see the NAS. My temp solution was to give my laptop a manual ip with a 4 in the third octet.